Adjusting shift phase of PWM dinamically does not work in STM32
I need to get two PWM signals (PWM1 and PWM2) from STM32F767 Nucleo board when programing with STM32CubeIDE, which are applied to a Full-Bridge DC-DC Converter. PWM2 must be shifted phase in reference to PWM1. I am using TIM1.Channel1 and TIM2.Channel1 for PWM generation, but TIM2 is syncronized as slave to the TIM1.Channel2, which works as "Compare no Output". I followed the next tutorial as baseline to reach this scope: Link to Tutorial
As result, the PWM signals describe the initial configuration of the program for the shift phase. But, I can not adjust the shifted phase dinamically in the range 0 to 180 degrees. This is important to control the voltage convertion process.
I used the next line code to start the PWM and compare modules of TIM1 and TIM2, and to adjust the CCR2 value of TIM2 to adjuste the shifted phase, but it does not work. I will thanks any usefull help.
/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM8_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  //HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1); // turn on complementary channel

  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  //HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_1); // turn on complementary channel
  
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    D1 = 0.20;
    // Shift phase adjusting for PWM1 and PWM2
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2, D1 * 960);

    //htim1.Instance->CCR2=D1*480;

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */


Start with what you know. Are you sure TIM2 is being triggered by TIM1.Ch2? Easy to check by changing the TIM1.Ch2 config and observing TIM2. Then, does configuring the CCR value at build time have an effect? Only once you've established that, worry about changing it dynamically.
